# How do I make an "in website proxy" like hidester.com/proxy? Is there anything already on GitHub like this?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I need to make a website similar to  https://hidester.com/proxy/.
My school doesn't have that many protections, just a firewall that blocks access to proxy websites on school computers. I want to self-host something on my network like that where I can put in a website and it will access it for me like a proxy. That way, the proxy is unblocked.  I don't want to use any chrome extensions or system software. Does software like that exist already on GitHub or if not, how would I go about making something like that using nodejs or nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alloyproxy, nodeunblocker, pydodge, and powermouse. There are more but these are easy to setup and I use on my site. My sites are hopelessjourney.ga and hopefuljourney.cf